# Ruby: Sort Dates by their closeness to some test date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have an array of dates.  I need to sort those dates by their **closeness** to some test_date. The dates in the array can be *before* or *after* that test_date.

My simple ruby program isn't getting it right.  My strategy is to convert each `Date` to a unix timestamp.  Then I do a custom sort by the absolute value of the difference between the dates and the test_date.

Here is that program:

```
require 'date'
test_date = DateTime.new(2017,2,3,4,5,6)

date1 = Date.new(2017,1,6)
date2 = Date.new(2017,1,5)
date3 = Date.new(2017,2,5)
date4 = Date.new(2017,2,6)
date5 = Date.new(2017,2,9)
date6 = Date.new(2017,2,1)
date7 = Date.new(2017,2,2)

dates_ary = date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7

sorted_dates = dates_ary.sort do |d1, d2|
    if( (d1.to_time.to_i - test_date.to_time.to_i).abs <= (d2.to_time.to_i - test_date.to_time.to_i).abs)
        d1 <=> d2
    else
        d2 <=> d1
    end
end

puts "expected order: "
puts "2017-02-02"
# pointed out in comments that 2017-02-05 will be closer than 2017-02-01 due to test_date having present hours, minutes, and seconds.
puts "2017-02-05"
puts "2017-02-01"
puts "2017-02-06"
puts "2017-02-09"
puts "2017-01-06"
puts "2017-01-05"
puts ''

puts 'actual order:'
sorted_dates.each {|d| puts d}
```

Also: if there is some existing ruby or rails method that sorts dates by their closeness to another date, let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect `date6` to come before `date3`? Are you sure you want to compare `Date`s and `DateTime`s?

Comment: I'm applying this to a rails project where the `test_date` represents the `created_at` which is a DateTime type, and some other attribute which is a Date type.

Comment: But why would `2017-02-01` come before `2017-02-05`? Do you mean to compare the `Date`s with just the date component of the `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes that is a good point.  Technically `2017-02-01` would be further away than `2017-02-05`, unless the `DateTime` is exactly at midnight in which case it would be a tie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` is redundant. Ruby will handle it:

```
sorted_dates = dates.sort do |d1, d2|
  (d1.to_time.to_i - test_date.to_time.to_i).abs <=> (d2.to_time.to_i - test_date.to_time.to_i).abs
end
```

Better:

```
sorted_dates = dates.sort_by do |date|
  (date.to_time.to_i - test_date.to_time.to_i).abs
end
```

Better:

```
sorted_dates = dates.sort_by { |date| (date - test_date).abs }
```

Comment: But this won't give the OP's desired output.

Comment: I corrected my posting so that the expected result is what is supposed to be returned.

Comment: Yes, the expected result is what is supposed to be returned, but what does that have to do with this question?